# Chrome DevTools sources webpack missing

Tags: angular, debugging, webpack

I cannot debug my Angular8 project since there is no webpack folder.
I start the application with like this: `ng build --watch --source-map`, and there are the .map files in the target folder, but chrome don't realize them. 
(the js source maps are enabled in devtools settings)

Answer (score -3):

Not sure I correctly understand your question, but usually you just

- run `ng serve`
- open http://localhost:4200
- use the debugger "open file" shortcut (with autocomplete) to find the source file your are looking for
- set breakpoints
- debug :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but even if i add .map files, they are minified and the prettyfying does not working. I used to debug as i just opened the webpack folder in sources, but now i did not see this `webpack` folder.

Comment: So my main problem is why on earth does webpack folder not appear?
Neither after i manually added .map files.

Comment: No idea if you have tried the above steps. If it isn't working in your current project, a strategy to narrow down the problem is to to create a new test project (simply keep the sample content) and check if it works there. If it works there (as it should), compare the config files if there is a difference. Another option is to remove & re-install the node_modules. Restarting the browser helps sometimes too if the dev tools behave strange...

Comment: i've created a test project, (and then an other) but it didn't work as well. The .map files are in the targetFolder besides the .js files, but still no webpack folder.

Comment: Hmm, still puzzled by your 'targetFolder' statement. If you run `ng serve` you don't have any target folder.

Comment: f course, sorry! i'v tried both `ng serve`, and `ng build --watch --sourceMap`

Comment: A new app with `ng serve` should work out of the box. That is very strange. Other options: try in another Browser. Check that you use a compatible node version. You could also try another angular version. Unlikely but not impossible that there is is a bug in the angular-cli version that is used in your project. You could check the release notes if there are source map fixes in the release after your version. Getting out of ideas. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I'm still trying!

Comment: Later turned out it was the webserves config which caused the problem.

Comment: @PéterCipriánOláh How did you solved this?  I'm facing the same issue...

Comment: @mk2683 backend side there was a config which did not allowed to reach .map.js files. the BE developer keeped that in secret...